# Trying to escape $, not working as I expected?

Tags: php

I'm trying to escape the character `$` so that it becomes a literal within a string I'm compiling. I thought that this would do the trick, but apparently not:

```
$html = $_POST['html'];
$sanitize = htmlspecialchars($html);
$sanitize = str_replace("$", "\$", $sanitize); // Addition.
```

Here's my base code posted as `html` (it was originally a sanitizer for html, the last part being an addition).

```
$rp = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
include($rp. "_static/inc/db_conn.php");

$conn = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass); mysql_select_db($db_name);
```

It produces:

```
$rp = realpath($_SERVER[\'DOCUMENT_ROOT\']);
include($rp. \"_static/inc/db_conn.php\");

$conn = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass); mysql_select_db($db_name);
```

It appears thus, that `htmlspecialchars()` is working as I'd expect it to, but not `str_replace()`.

Any help/answers would be appreciated (heads up, I've never used `str_replace()` before, so I just went as per the PHP doc).

Comment: "It appears thus, that htmlspecialchars() is working as I'd expect " --- `htmlspecialchars` doesn't add slashes to quotes, magic quotes does

Comment: Oh, so what is `htmlspecialchars()` doing then?

Comment: why don't you just look at manual? http://php.net/htmlspecialchars

Comment: One thing I never do is implement my own sanitation functions. Because I know that there might be something I may be missing out. I would simply prefer to use tested libraries like HTMLPurifier despite its large footprint. Just my opinion though

Comment: Ah, well thanks for the reference, in this instance it doesn't matter (I think I may have even used it intentionally as it outputs the data into a text-area (I built this a while back)), but it's good to know for the future.

Comment: Oh nvm. The OP isn't handling richtext, thus the `htmlspecialchars`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash as well.

```
$sanitize = str_replace("$", "\\$", $sanitize);
```

Alternatively, you could use single quotes.

```
$sanitize = str_replace('$', '\$', $sanitize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using single quotes instead of double quotes, eg '$' instead of "$"  The double quotes tell PHP to look for variables in your string, which you don't want it to do.